# Logstash Twitter input for Stock symbol

Tags: twitter, logstash

I can't seems to use twitter stock symbol on logstash twitter input. It throws exception if I tried to use the `$` sign

```
input {
 twitter {
        # add your data
        consumer_key => "*******************"
        consumer_secret => "*******************"
        oauth_token => "***********************"
        oauth_token_secret => "***********************"
        keywords => ["AAPL"]
        full_tweet => true
    }
}
```

I need to filter only the stock related tweets in the keywords

`keywords => ["$AAPL"]`

This shows up in my console if I tried to user the `$` symbol in the `keywords`

`` 5/lib/logstash/inputs/twitter.rb:88:in `run'", "/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:174:in `inputworker'", "/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:168:in `start_input'"], :level=>:warn}
 {:exception=>Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, :backtrace=>["/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/twitter-5.12.0/lib/twitter/streaming/response.rb:21:in `on_headers_complete'", "org/ruby_http_parser/RubyHttpParser.java:370:in `<<'", "/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/twitter-5.12.0/lib/twitter/streaming/response.rb:16:in `<<'", "/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/twitter-5.12.0/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:22:in `stream'", "/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/twitter-5.12.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:116:in `request'", "/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/twitter-5.12.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:36:in `filter'", "/home/user11/opt/tools/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-twitter-0.1 ``

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: Where is the `$` sign? What is the exception?

Comment: @OfriRaviv, the ````$```` sign is used in the keywords

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: @OfriRaviv, I updated my question to show to error

Comment: Try replacing `$` with `\$`: `keywords => ["\$AAPL"]`

Comment: @OfriRaviv, I tried that also, no luck.